# Cómo filtrar un arreglo y devolver su valor dentro de una funcion?

Tags: javascript, array, typescript, filtro

El ejercicio de typescript parece muy sencillo:
toma un arreglo de la siguiente forma arr = [1,'a','b',2] y dentro de una función, modificándolo y devuelve un arreglo con sólo números sin crear un arreglo nuevo.

```
function unaFunc(arr: any[]) {
    //escribe tu función aquí
    //yo intenté lo siguiente: return arr.filter(e => typeof e === 'number')
}

let arr = [1,'a','b',2]
unaFunc(arr)
console.log(arr)
```

Pero eso no da el resultado esperado. Simpre devuelve el arreglo original (es decir: [1,'a','b',2])

Alguna idea? Gracias

Comment: De hecho si te devuelve el arreglo filtrado, el problema es que estás imprimiendo el arreglo `arr` y no lo que te devuelve la función `unaFunc(arr)`

Comment: claro, pero el ejercicio es así como está. El console.log es sobre la variable "arr". Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Asígnale a `arr` lo que te devuelve la función, `arr = unaFunc(arr)`

Comment: lo único que puedo hacer es modificar la función

Answer (score 1):

te lo resolvi en javascript, pero puedes pasarlo a typescript. El problema es que el metodo .filter() es un metodo que no altera el array original, sino que crea uno nuevo. En este ejemplo lo que hice fue recorrer el array y almacenar el indice de todas las strings en otro array `toRemove`. Luego de esto simplemente itere sobre cada uno de sus elementos y los elimine del array original. Si te preguntas por que use el metodo `reverse()`, fue para poder eliminar los elementos dentro del `for` sin que el hecho de estar dentro de un bucle causara problemas.

```
function unaFunc(arr) {
    const toRemove = [];
    for (let e in arr) {
        typeof arr[e] !== 'number' && toRemove.push(e);
    }
    for ( let e of toRemove.reverse() ) {
        arr.splice( e, 1 );
    }
}

let arr = [1,'a','b',2];
unaFunc(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Gracias Fabio! pero una de las consignas es no crear un array nuevo

Comment: El OP pide que sea en **TypeScript**, ten en cuenta que **TypeScript y Javascript no son iguales**

Comment: ese mismo codigo facilmente lo podrias pasar a typescript... Y creo que a lo que se refieren es que debes modificar el array original, y no devolver un array nuevo en la funcion

Answer (score 1):

Planteo una solución similar a la de @Fabio, pero con un solo *loop*.
En vez de recorrer el *array* para sacar los índices de los elementos que no sean de tipo `number` y después volver a recorrerlo para eliminar los elementos de esos índices (además del coste del `reverse` del *array* de índices); podemos iterar una vez, haciendo la comprobación y el borrado del elemento en la misma iteración y controlando el índice.

```
const filterFn = <R>(arr: (number | R)[]): void => {
    const isNumber = (element: number | R): element is number => {
        return typeof element === 'number';
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        const element = arr[i];
        if (!isNumber(element)) {
            // Eliminamos el elemento
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            // Decrementamos el index para 
            // hacer referencia al siguiente
            // elemento del array
            --i;
        }
    }
}
```

La sutil diferencia es la expresión `--i`.
Cuando eliminamos un elemento, debemos decrementar el índice para apuntar al siguiente elemento del *array*. Sin decrementarlo, estaríamos "saltándonos" un elemento de la lista.

Con un caso práctico, supongamos que `arr` es `[1, 'a', 'b', 15]`; cuando `i` vale `1`, `isNumber('a')` devolverá `false`, por lo que eliminaremos ese elemento. Ahora, `arr` es `[1, 'b', 15]`. En la siguiente iteración, `i` valdrá `2`, por tanto, `arr[i]` será el tercer elemento, `15`. Nos hemos "saltado" el elemento `'b'`.
Después de invocar a `slice`, todos los elementos después de `i`, hacen un "*shift*" a la izquierda. Por eso `i` debe ajustarse.

> *Disclaimer*
> La firma de la función `filterFn<>` puede cambiar, sólo le he querido otorgar una firma más explícita por el bien de la explicación, pero `function unaFunc(arr: any[])` también valdría.

Espero que sirva.

Answer (score 0):

```
function unaFunc(arr: any[]) {
    
    let counter = 0    

     for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        const element = arr[index];
        if (typeof element === 'number') {
            counter = counter + 1 
        } else {
            for (let ind = index; ind < arr.length; ind++) {
                const ele = arr[ind];
                if (typeof ele === 'number') {
                    arr[index] = ele
                }
            }            
        }       
        
    }    
    arr.length = counter
}

let arr = [1,'a','b',2]
unaFunc(arr)
console.log(arr)
```

con ese código puedo devolver el resultado del ejercicio, pero no aplica para un array más largo con más datos, ya que no devuelve correctamente los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Usando solo métodos de arreglos, en un ciclo puedes verificar si existe un elemento que no sea numérico y eliminarlo.

- [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) - Si encuentra un elemento que cumple con la condición devuelve su posición (índice), de lo contrario, devuelve -1
- [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) - **Cambia** el contenido del arreglo, sin generar uno nuevo y, cuando proporcionas dos parámetros, el primero es la posición de inicio y el segundo la cantidad de elementos a eliminar

```js
function unaFunc(arr) {
    let found = arr.findIndex(e => typeof e != 'number');
    while(found >= 0) {
        arr.splice(found, 1);
        found = arr.findIndex(e => typeof e != 'number');
    }
}

let arr = [1,'a','b',2];
unaFunc(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Supongo que para hacerlo *Typescript* solo debes asignar tipo al parámetro de la función:

```
function unaFunc(arr: any[]) {
    let found = arr.findIndex(e => typeof e != 'number');
    while(found >= 0) {
        arr.splice(found, 1);
        found = arr.findIndex(e => typeof e != 'number');
    }
}

let arr = [1,'a','b',2];
unaFunc(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

**Duda:** ¿En *Typescript* también es opcional finalizar líneas con `;`?

Comment: *Typescript* transpila a *JavaScript*, por lo que sí, también es opcional el *semi-colon* al final de cada línea, aunque la mayoría de guías de estilo lo desaconsejan.

Comment: Perfecto, @VRoxa. Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Por si te sirve, yo acostumbro a usar el [*Typescript playground*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) para hacer pruebas o "mini *scripts*" o, por ejemplo, para escribir y probar mis respuestas que redacto en SO (las de TS, claro), c:

Comment: Por supuesto que va a servirme, muchas gracias.